# How can I play the Stop it Slender workshop?

Tags: steam, garrys-mod

I've just made an account on steam, and subscribed to Garry's Mod, which said once I subscribed, the game would download immediately. Nothing happened. Do I need to buy Garry's mod or something? I thought this was a free game, I don't understand. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subscribe for a garry's mod addon, it will automatically download. You can see this as a sort of DLC.

To play it, you have to buy Garry's Mod

Comment: You also need to have Counter Strike for the game to actually run.

Comment: For most Gmod addons you need Counter-Strike: Source for them to work properly. This is due to most textures being used from that game.